# Fine tuning max.poll.record Kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm currently working on a java Kafka consumer program an struggling to properly setup my configuration.
My root issue is that my consumer is too laggy and consume multiple time the same event.

[Kafka consumer log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyeCu.png)

48! occurence of the same event on a 8 day range.

So, I was thinking of setup a low value for max.poll.record to manage less event per poll and avoid duplicate.
`properties.setProperty("max.poll.records", Configuration.MAXPOLLRECORD); //100?`

But I have no idea if it's the proper way to handle it.

Does anyone could enlight me about this ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to show in your image? I see some id, and a bunch of log files? What if the first file is a create event, and the rest are update events, and the very last is a delete? The image you've shown proves nothing without seeing the actual record content

Answer (score 0):

If your producer is sending duplicates, you need to use external data store to track the deserialized record data for uniqueness, and/or if successfully processed. For example - query the store for every produced event to not send again, or query for every polled event to check if it's already been seen; Kafka doesn't do this for you.

For example, if offset 1 and 2 have the same serialized data, Kafka doesn't know about this - it only sees bytes at *unique offsets* (and timestamps), so the records are not "duplicates", therefore consumer configuration alone will not solve your problem.

For starters, use a transactional producer and enable idempotence, then you can enable consumer read-isolation to handle transactions, but that still won't fix "duplicated information" within the topic.